# TypeScript - property does not exist on object after parsing with toml

Tags: typescript, configuration, toml

My TypeScript project is modular and has several config files.
I chose [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) for the configuration files as it's a really intuitive language.

Also, I got a `main.toml` where you can enable/disable the modules.
My config class looks like this. It's made for creating multiple configs from it that are automatically parsed.

```
import { parse } from 'toml';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

export class Config {
    private readonly _name: string;
    private readonly _path: string;
    private _config: object;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this._name = name;
        this._path = join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'config', `${name}.toml`);
        this._config = this.load();
    }

    public load(): object {
        let config: object = {};
        try {
            config = parse(readFileSync(this._path).toString());
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.code === 'ENOENT') {
                throw new Error(`config ${this._name}.toml was not found!`);
            } else {
                throw new Error(error);
            }
        }
        return config;
    }

    get config(): object {
        return this._config;
    }
}
```

This is how my main file looks where I want to use the `main.toml` to activate other modules:

```
import { Config } from './init/config';

let config: object = {};
try {
    config = new Config('main').config;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
    process.exit(1);
}

for (const key in config.modules) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(config.modules, key) && config.modules[key]) {
        require(`./modules/${key}/${key}`);
    } else {
        zoya.info(`skipping module ${key}...`);
    }
}
```

Now I have the problem that the typescript compiler gives me the following error each time I use `config.modules`:

```
TS2339: Property 'modules' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

I could just suppress it with `@ts-ignore` which works fine by the way but I think that's some bad practice and I want to know if I can somehow prevent this.

I also tried other TOML parsers like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ltd/j-toml) one which I hoped would make a difference but I get the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript can't infer what the structure of your parsed config is. Remember that Typescript exists at compile-time, but not runtime, and your parsed config object exists at runtime but not at compile time.

You're telling Typescript that your parsed config is of type `object`, but `object` doesn't have a `modules` property.

You have two options here:

1. Define `_config` as `any` rather than `object`. This will tell Typescript that that object can be of *any* type, which means it will essentially not be typechecked.
2. Define interfaces for your config objects, so Typescript knows what types it should expect from them. Trivially:

```
interface ConfigDef {
   modules: SomeType[]
}

let config: ConfigDef = { modules: [] };
try {
    config = new Config('main').config as ConfigDef;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

Or, more strictly, using generics (which is probably better):

```
export class Config<T> {
    private readonly _name: string;
    private readonly _path: string;
    private _config: T;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this._name = name;
        this._path = join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'config', `${name}.toml`);
        this._config = this.load();
    }

    public load(): T {
        let config: T = {};
        try {
            config = parse(readFileSync(this._path).toString()) as T;
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.code === 'ENOENT') {
                throw new Error(`config ${this._name}.toml was not found!`);
            } else {
                throw new Error(error);
            }
        }
        return config;
    }

    get config(): T {
        return this._config;
    }
}

// ...

let config: ConfigDef = { modules: [] };
try {
    config = new Config<ConfigDef>('main').config;
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am now trying to use the generic method you pointed out as all my configs have different structures and I don't want to make interfaces for each of them. Currently having the problem with `let config: T = {};` since `{}` is not assignable to `T`. TypeScript says: 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{}'. And even if I used generics, how would TypeScript 'know' if there was a module property?

Comment: Right, whoops. You probably need to pass in an initial empty object (or define config as `Partial<T>`, though that's less safe). When you use generics, you pass an interface which specifies which properties that instance of the config expects to see.

Comment: Worth noting: If you want strong typing, you won't get away without making an interface per config type produced. Runtime reflection is out of scope for Typescript.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for clarification. This seems to work. :)